# Force <div>s to keep to one line in <td> cell

Tags: html, css, jinja2

I'm trying to loop through some data passed into a Jinja2 template and populate a table.
I would like to split each `<td>` cell into more sub-columns **if there is more information**, the number of sub-columns within the `<td>` is dynamic.

### Example 1

I would like each `<td>` to result in something like this (i.e. no matter how many sub-columns within each `<td>`, the new sub-column will be displayed in the same line):
[image]

### Example 2 ##

In this example, each new sub-column within the `<td>` is display below the previous one (I do not want this):
[image]

If I take this little snippet of code and open it in the browser it works as I want it to (example 1).

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
.cell {
    display: block;
}
.col {
    float:left;
    /*display: inline;*/
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<table style="border:solid">
    <thead>
        <tr><th>Example 1</th>
        <th>Example 2</th>
        <th>Example 3</th></tr>
    </thead>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div class="cell">
                <div class='col'>
                    item 1 <br />
                    item 2 <br />
                    item 3 <br />
                </div>
                <div class='col'>
                    item 1 <br />
                    item 2 <br />
                    item 3 <br />
                </div>
                <div class='col'>
                    item 1 <br />
                    item 2 <br />
                    item 3 <br />
                </div>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div class="cell">

                <div class='col'>
                    item 1 <br />
                    item 2 <br />
                    item 3 <br />
                </div>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div class="cell">
                <div class='col'>
                    item 1 <br />
                    item 2 <br />
                    item 3 <br />
                </div>
                <div class='col'>
                    item 1 <br />
                    item 2 <br />
                    item 3 <br />
                </div>

            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>

</table>
</body>
</html>
```

However it does not work as expected in the template. If I use the same styling, the `<td>` does not widen to accommodate the new sub-column. The `<td>` does widen accommodate the text within each column.

```
<table>
<thead>Some information about all the cells</thead>
{% for person in list_of_people%}
<tr>

<td>
  <div class="cell">
  {% for item in person.activity %}
    <div class='col'>
    {% for element in item %}
      {{ loop.index }}
        {% if element['correct'] == True %}
          &#10004;
        {% else %}
          &#10007;
        {% endif %}
      <br />
    {% endfor %}
    SCORE <br />= {{stats[0]}} / {{stats[2]}}
    <br />
    </div> <!-- col -->
  {% endfor %}
  </div> <!-- attempt -->
</td>

</tr>
{% endfor %}
</table>
```

How can I ensure that each `<div>` inside each `<td>` stays in the same line and doesn't get pushed below the previous one?

Comment: Why are you using `div`s to display `tabular` data?

Comment: you can most likely achieve this with `display: table-cell` through `CSS` ... but then again, why aren't you using tables.

Comment: I am using a `<table>` but within the table I want to divide the `<td>` up into further columns depending on whether or not there is more information to put in there...

Answer (score 4):

Using `display: flex` in the outer `div.attempt` will prevent the inner div from going on to the next line.

I used flexbox like so (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16280040/css3-flexbox-display-box-vs-flexbox-vs-flex)):

```
.attempt {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Edited answer.

Consider using a non-block element for the columns within the td; a span element works.

This would look like this:

```
table
  tr
    td
      span blammy /span
      span hooty /spam
      span kapow /span
    /td
  /tr
/table
```

You should be able to set a width on the span elements so the columns line up from row to row.

Also, if necessary, `display:inline-block` might help.

Here is an [example fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/burhans/48g8H/)

Comment: I considered the `<table>` within the `<td>`.. do you feel it is a better solution?

Answer (score 0):

use `.col{float:left; width:33%;}` Result: http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: What if there is only one column in that `<td>`? I wasn't that clear but not every `<td>` in a row or column would have more columns inside it.

Comment: make a `for` loop in `<div class='col3 {% for element in item %}{% if loop.length == 2 %}col2{% elseif loop.length == 1%}col1{% endif %}{% endfor %} '>` . And use the css for each column class: `.col1{width:100%;} .col2{width:50%} .col3{width:33%}`

Comment: This is a good suggestion, however, there could be infinitely many sub-columns within the `<td>`.

Comment: Then generate a table for each column. And wrap each `element` in a `td` of that `table`

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using `div`'s in a `table` to create columns? You can achieve the same effect with only a `table`:

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th colspan="3">Example</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        item 1 <br />
        item 2 <br />
        item 3 <br />
      </td>
      <td>
        item 1 <br />
        item 2 <br />
        item 3 <br />
      </td>
      <td>
        item 1 <br />
        item 2 <br />
        item 3 <br />
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

[Example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vrDiB)