# Why are my elements not equal in width?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to have the widths equal to each other automagically so this way I can have any number of elements and variable text.  In this case, the elements are not consistent in size.  Any ideas?

[Js Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/utcy8ab1/)

HTML:

```
<div class="tempTable">
    <a href="a"  class="childThing" >A</a>
    <a href="b" class="childThing ">sdfdssdfsdfdsfdsfdsffsdfsdfsdf </a>
    <a href="c"  class="childThing" >sdfsdf</a>
    <a href="d"   class="childThing" >sdfdsf</a>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.tempTable {
    display: box;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -moz-box;
    -webkit-box-align: start;
    -moz-box-align: start;
    box-align: start;
    max-width: 1000px;
}

.childThing {
   -webkit-box-flex: 1;
    -moz-box-flex: 1;
    box-flex: 1;
    text-align: center;
    display: block;
    color: #fff ;
    background-color: #4C839D;
    font-size:15px;
    border:none;
    position: relative;
    outline:0;
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Flexbox not giving equal width to elements](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25066214/flexbox-not-giving-equal-width-to-elements)

Answer (score 1):

You can have a css like this:

```
#wrapper {
    display: table;
    table-layout: fixed;

    width:90%;
    height:100px;
    background-color:Gray;
}
#wrapper div {
    display: table-cell;
    height:100px;
}
```

Here is a working version:
http://jsfiddle.net/g4dGz/1028/

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
.tempTable {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
  -webkit-flex-direction: row;
      -ms-flex-direction: row;
          flex-direction: row;
  max-width: 1000px;
}
.childThing {
  -webkit-box-flex: 1;
  -webkit-flex-grow: 1;
      -ms-flex-positive: 1;
          flex-grow: 1;
  -webkit-flex-basis: 0;
      -ms-flex-preferred-size: 0;
          flex-basis: 0;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff ;
  background-color: #4C839D;
  font-size: 15px;
  border: none;
  outline: 0;
}
```

demo: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GJNxXZ

See also: [CSS3 Flexbox: display: box vs. flexbox vs. flex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16280040/css3-flexbox-display-box-vs-flexbox-vs-flex)

Answer (score 0):

The `block` **value** for the `display` **property** makes the **box** of an element break a line and take the full width of its container. This is the default value of the `p` and `div` elements.

Instead, use the `display` property to make your elements act like **table elements**, since the size of their boxes is bound together.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="table">
    <a href="a">A</a>
    <a href="b">Lorem ipsum sit amet</a>
    <a href="c">C</a>
    <a href="d">D</a>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.table a {
    display: table-row;
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5kdva2k6/)

Answer (score 0):

> ...widths equal to each other automagically

if you set a `flex-basis` property it will fix a width;
if needed, `word-wrap: break-word` will wrap text.

Check the **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/maio/utcy8ab1/4/)**