# detecting flex-box support with CSS3 @supports

Tags: css

I am planning on implementing flexbox solutions to my layout if they are supported and I am going to feature-detect if they are supported with CSS3's `@support{...}` queries.

But what should I test is supported? Since feature `@support` queries look for support of a given style and then implement styles if supported, of what should I look for support?

In other words, what style do all implementations of flexbox support?

I would think it would be the `display:box;` for the 2009 flexbox implementation, `display:flexbox;` for the shortlived 2011 implementation, and `display:flex;` for the current and final implementation of the spec?

Answer (score 3):

Flexbox (Standard draft) support + Feature Query support:

- Opera added support for both in the same version (12.1)
- Firefox added support for both in the same version (22), but didn't support flex-wrap until 28
- Android added support for both in the same version (4.4)
- Chrome added support for Flexbox in 21, but didn't support feature queries until 28

No browser that exclusively supports either of the old Flexbox drafts has support for feature queries.

- [Browser support for Flexbox](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox)
- [Browser support for Feature Queries](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-featurequeries)

The only practical use for feature queries in combination with Flexbox at this point in time is to detect if a browser supports `flex-wrap: wrap`.  However, the number of browsers still in use that support `display: flex` and not `flex-wrap: wrap` is pretty much the point where you can consider them to be statistically insignificant.

```
.foo {
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: -webkit-flex;
}

@supports (flex-wrap: wrap) {
    display: flex;
}
```

Related: [Flexible box model - display : flex, box, flexbox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15662578/flexible-box-model-display-flex-box-flexbox)

Answer (score 2):

The browsers that implement `display:box` / `display:flexbox` and `display:flex` are unlikely to support `@supports`.  Furthermore, until yesterday, Firefox did not support `flex-wrap`.  Meanwhile, Internet Explorer 11, while supporting `display:flex`, does not support `@supports`.

So you are better off with a JavaScript solution like Modernizr or just assume the browser supports `display:flex` if your users are likely to use Firefox/Chrome on any platform or MSIE11 on Windows 8. If you would like to support iPhone, remember to `-webkit-` prefix and flex properties and use `display:-webkit-flex`.

Since flexbox automatically overrides floats and the `flex` property allows you to override width, chances are you can just mix the CSS for non-`display:flex` browsers with those that do.