# Equivalent of Chrome CSS display: -webkit-box on other browser

Tags: css

I was trying to add a css property `display` on a project I am trying to continue, and just found out this property I am not aware of.

I tried to search on google but it seems there is only display: -webkit-box or display: box

As far as I know `-webkit` is for chrome and safari, So I am wondering if there is any equivalent of this in Mozilla ? like `-moz-box`? or in IE / Edge `-ms-box`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`display: box;` is 2009 flexbox spec...

See here: [Flexible box model - display : flex, box, flexbox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15662578/flexible-box-model-display-flex-box-flexbox)

Comment: thanks for the link! I guess I need to read more about css3 property looks like I am outdated already!