# CSS display: -webkit-box not working in Internet Explorer 11

Tags: css, internet-explorer, flexbox

Question: Is there any CSS element that does the same as `display: -webkit-box;` ? It seems that IE 11 isn't supporting this element. Please help me out!

Comment: In general WebKit isn't supported by IE, you should use flexbox instead.

Comment: To say it more accurately, IE doesn't use the Webkit rendering engine to which that prefix applies. That's also extremely old syntax.

Comment: @isherwood: I suspect the reason they're asking this at all is because virtually every other non-WebKit browser does support -webkit-box and a variety of other -webkit- bits, allowing code that relied on the legacy syntax to continue working seamlessly.

Comment: display:flex is supported by IE11 but parts flexbox are not supported by IE11 - https://caniuse.com/#search=flex

Answer (score 4):

It used to be: `display:box` for the first iterations of Flexbox (~2009).

Nowadays `display: flex` is used. I'd recommend using that.

Original answer: [Flexible box model - display : flex, box, flexbox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15662578/flexible-box-model-display-flex-box-flexbox)

In case you need more references on Flexbox I found this very helpful: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/